# Spring security - allow navigation but protecting some pages

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, web-applications, authentication, spring-security

I would like to allow the user to navigate through the site but restrict access to some operations/pages where he must be logged in to do so. How do I achieve this using spring security configuration?

I'm not sure if spring security is the way though.

Comment: Have you looked at the reference manual and some sample applications? Your question is really too broad as it stands.

Comment: Yes, I've spent already some hours around this... and only found examples that are the other way around... I mean, examples that block the user all over the place unless he logs in. I'd rather let the user do everything and then make him to login at certain point.

Comment: It's still not really clear what you mean - you can restrict access to as much or as little of your application as you want using basic access control configuration options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

within your spring security configuration, you can do something like this:

> ```
> <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" requires-channel="https" />
> <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" requires-channel="https" />
> <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" requires-channel="any" />
> ```

Then prefix all of your protected pages with /secure/.  This will allow people to navigate the entire site except pages in /secure/ and /admin/

Also, instead of `ROLE_USER`, you can use `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` (as opposed to `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` or `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`)

The `requires-channel` is only if you are using https, which you should be if you are trying to protect content.